# Date time in access.log file

Tags: linux, proxy, squid, time

Hai,

- How can i add human date and time format in squid access.log file?
- What change i want to make in squid.conf file ?
- I want that my log file will update with normal date and time format , How can i do it ?
- If i use tail comment to view log file , i want to get human date and time format. What i want to do for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
perl -p -e 's/^([0-9]*)/"[".localtime($1)."]"/e' < access.log
```

could help you with the last part (`tail`-ing the log). Found it on a Squid mailing list.

Comment: This will help to view log file with human date and time format.